# Compile mysql for AES 256bits

Tags: mysql, linux, encryption, aes, opensuse

According to [mysql document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html)

> "Encoding with a 128-bit key length is used, but you can extend it up to 256 bits by modifying the source."

But they didn't seem to provide instruction where to change. Anyone experience with this situation? which source file should change?

Note: I use [these steps to compile](http://tripanel.net/tutorials/mysql_compile.html).

Comment: The biggest problem with the function it's not the key length but the mode. It uses ECB so there is no block chaining and no initial vector. It's not suitable for encrypting sensitive data. For example, the same password will always generate the same ciphertext so it's very easy to guess the common used passwords.

Comment: You're right. This is a very primary state to secure application data. CBC is the next step, that encrypt/decrypt at data access layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found little help from mysql [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/mysql@lists.mysql.com/msg73071.html)

file include/my_aes.h

```
#define AES_KEY_LENGTH 128 /* must be 128 192 or 256 */
```

as I'm using OpenSuSe 11.1 need to have following tools

```
sudo zypper install gcc gcc-c++ ncurses-devel
```

then just compile it by this instruction - [here](http://tripanel.net/tutorials/mysql_compile.html)

**Credit to LenZ and tripanel.net**

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be a more maintainable solution to carry out the encryption in the client application.

Moreover, you'll also then get the benefit of then having the data carried over the network encrypted and not sending the key over the network (Of course you can use SSL to connect to mysql to mitigate this anyway).

If this does not seem like a good approach, please post your requirements.

You probably do not want to compile your own mysql binaries; there are more useful things for developers to do than building their own mysql binaries. MySQL / Sun's ones are extensively tested and won't contain performance regressions (we hope).

---

The mysql AES_ENCRYPT() functions are also potentially not secure because they haven't documented

- How they hash the password into the key
- What cipher mode they use

If they're done in a vulnerable way, the encryption could be very weak. It depends on your use-case whether this matters.

Comment: The requirement is to use AES256 encryption in database with AES_ENCRYPT function. The document from mysql is not very clear but they do quite well documented in the source code. I have managed myself to solve the problem. Thanks for your suggestion.